# Does a heavy crossbow allow sneak attack damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, sneak-attack, ranged-attack

Can a Rogue use a heavy crossbow with sneak attack if the rogue player has the ability to use a heavy crossbow?

Comment: I don't understand the down-votes for this question. It's basic, but it's something that has changed from previous versions. This question could settle arguments for tables.

Comment: The down votes are because the sneak attack description is extremely clear about this. "The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon." That's why people are downvoting this. It's a question that says, "Read me the basic rules." I don't want to get too offensive, but this is the same as asking if a Paladin can use a Longbow to trigger Smite.

Answer (score 20):

Sneak Attack requires conditions to be met in order to apply. They can be found in PHB page 96 or [in the SRD](http://www.5esrd.com/classes/rogue/).

There is no reason for Sneak Attack not to trigger with a ranged Heavy Crossbow attack, if all requirements are met.

Comment: Unless you hit someone with it.

Comment: @Dale M - Unless you hit someone with the crossbow itself as a melee weapon attack. - Fixed for accuracy.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli Does throwing the crossbow at them count as a ranged attack? :p

Comment: @DavidHarkness - Technically, yes. Improvised weapon attack and less effective than firing, but definitely doable.

Comment: @DavidHarkness if you have another question, go ahead and [ask](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new one.

Answer (score 7):

Sneak attack (PHB p.96):

> The attack must use a finesse or a *ranged* weapon.

A heavy crossbow is a ranged weapon and so may be used to sneak attack when used as such (rather than an improvised weapon for instance).